# TRIGGER to INCREMENT after INSERT

Tags: mysql, triggers, sql-update, sql-insert

I'm trying to create a trigger that increments the cardcount in faction table after an INSERT into card if a row's`faction.factionname` matches `cards.faction` of the INSERT.

so far I have tried a couple of different methods but the code below is my closest guess

```
create table cards(
    cardid int not null,
    faction varchar(255) not null,
    primary key(cardid)
);

create table faction(
    factionname varchar(255) not null,
    cardcount int not null,
    primary key(factionname)
);


create trigger updatecountinsert
    after insert on cards
    for each row
begin
    update faction
    set cardcount=carcount+1
    where last_insert_id().faction=faction.factionname
end;
```

Basically if I insert values(11,'x') x being the faction if a row of  faction has factionname=x
the trigger should 
increase that row's "cardcount" by 1

Comment: What doesn't work with this approach? What is your actual question? Please be specific

Comment: "where last_insert_id().faction=faction.factionname "   line claims that there is a syntactical error. I'm trying to make the trigger at the end of the code work. also thanks for the edit

Comment: You do have what appears to be a `carcount` instead of `cardcount` - does fixing that help?

Comment: oh, my bad. I fixed it but im still getting the same error.

Comment: You typically use OLD and NEW in triggers; not last_insertid(). ...and even if last_insert_id() were needed, [it does not return a row you could use to reference fields like that](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/information-functions.html#function_last-insert-id), and relies on an auto incremented id your tables are lacking.

Comment: What is the error? We want to help you, but we don't have your eyes. You need to give all the relevant information up front

Comment: i'll edit the code for just the relevant lines

Answer (score 0):

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE TRIGGER updatecountinsert
AFTER INSERT ON cards
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
   -- NEW is used to qualify references values of the row that was just inserted
   -- e.g. NEW.faction is a reference to the value in the faction column
   UPDATE faction f
      SET f.cardcount = f.cardcount + 1
    WHERE f.factionname = NEW.faction ;
END;
$$

DELIMITER ;
```